# Tagging somebody you are not friends with

Tags: facebook, facebook-photos, facebook-tags

I have a photo from a guy I want to tag, but we are not friends and I don’t want us to become friends on Facebook only so I can tag him.

We have a friend in common, so we *are related*.

But when I type his name on the tag, Facebook suggests me people I don’t even have mutual friends with.

Is there a way to tag a specific person on a photo? Maybe something like `@[[user.id]]`?